# Dynamic Leader Board Sorting in Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, dynamic, leaderboard

[image]

I would like to create a formula to dynamically sort columns "AI" an "AJ" as new scores are inputted by the user. I simply want the "TOTAL" / "AG" column to be the driver of the sort. I have used the "small" function in excel, but this does not handle duplicate scores.

What is the best way to dynamically sort the "TOTAL" column by displaying name and score in ascending order in columns AI and AJ?

Comment: Was going to post an answer, but it looks as if results are only shown every third row in your setup so it wouldn't work.

Comment: If you can get it to work with no rows in between that would be great too!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're using a formula like this to get the sorted scores

```
=SMALL(AG$11:AG$23,ROWS(AG10:AG$10))
```

If you have the unsorted scores in AG, letters in AH and sorted scores in AI, try this in AJ

```
=INDEX(AH$11:AH$23,SMALL(IF(AG$11:AG$23=AI11,ROW(AG$11:AG$23)-ROW(AG$10)),1+COUNTIF(AI$10:AI10,AI11)))
```

This is assuming scores start in row 11 and finish in row 23, but would need adjusting if (as appears from your screenshot) the scores are in every third row.

Has to be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Here is the modified formula for AI assuming scores are every third row

```
=IF(MOD(ROWS(AG$8:AG10),3),"",SMALL(AG$11:AG$47,ROWS(AG$8:AG10)/3))
```

and this is the modified formula for AJ

```
=IF(AI11="","",INDEX(AH$11:AH$47,SMALL(IF(AG$11:AG$47=AI11,ROW(AG$11:AG$47)-ROW(AG$10)),1+COUNTIF(AI$10:AI10,AI11))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - enjoy the tournament!